# How to populate a chart with a range of date? from: date to: date

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js, bar-chart

I need to populate a chart to create a report with a range of dates, i already implemented the chart in the website but i don't know how to populate it with my data and to show the data from one date to another. I've looked online but haven't found anything that could helped me. I don't know js or html all i've learned is by searching online and playing with the code.

I found an online example but don't know how to implement it on the barChart function. I've tried putting the code here but i'm having difficulty putting it complete it. This is the link https://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/zxrkh502/

This is my HTML code

```js
if ($("#barChartSales").length) {
      var ChartColor = ['red']
      var barChartCanvas = $("#barChartSales").get(0).getContext("2d");
      var barChart = new Chart(barChartCanvas, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
          labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
          datasets: [{

            data: [15, 28, 14, 22, 38, 30, 40, 70, 85, 50, 23, 20],
            backgroundColor: ChartColor[0],
            borderColor: ChartColor[0],
            borderWidth: 0
          }]
        },
        options: {
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: true,
          layout: {
            padding: {
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              top: 0,
              bottom: 0
            }
          },
          scales: {
            xAxes: [{
              display: true,
              scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Sales by year',
                fontSize: 12,
                lineHeight: 2
              },
              ticks: {
                fontColor: '#bfccda',
                stepSize: 50,
                min: 0,
                max: 150,
                autoSkip: true,
                autoSkipPadding: 15,
                maxRotation: 0,
                maxTicksLimit: 10
              },
              gridLines: {
                display: false,
                drawBorder: false,
                color: 'transparent',
                zeroLineColor: '#eeeeee'
              }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
              display: true,
              scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'revenue by sales',
                fontSize: 12,
                lineHeight: 2
              },
              ticks: {
                display: true,
                autoSkip: false,
                maxRotation: 0,
                fontColor: '#bfccda',
                stepSize: 50,
                min: 0,
                max: 150
              },
              gridLines: {
                drawBorder: false
              }
            }]
          },
          legend: {
            display: false
          },
          legendCallback: function (chart) {
            var text = [];
            text.push('<div class="chartjs-legend"><ul>');
            for (var i = 0; i < chart.data.datasets.length; i++) {
              // console.log(chart.data.datasets[i]); // see what's inside the obj.
              text.push('<li>');
              text.push('<span style="background-color:' + chart.data.datasets[i].backgroundColor + '">' + '</span>');
              text.push(chart.data.datasets[i].label);
              text.push('</li>');
            }
            text.push('</ul></div>');
            return text.join("");
          },
          elements: {
            point: {
              radius: 0
            }
          }
        }
      });
      document.getElementById('bar-traffic-sales').innerHTML = barChart.generateLegend();
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.js" integrity="sha512-G8JE1Xbr0egZE5gNGyUm1fF764iHVfRXshIoUWCTPAbKkkItp/6qal5YAHXrxEu4HNfPTQs6HOu3D5vCGS1j3w==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12">
<div class="dash__box dash__box--shadow dash__box--radius dash__box--bg-white u-s-m-b-30">
<div class="dash__box dash__box--shadow dash__box--radius dash__box--bg-white u-s-m-b-30">
    <div class="dash__pad-2">

              <h4 class="card-title mb-0">Total Sales


              </h4>

              <h5 class = "card-title mb-0"> 
                  From: <input  type="date" name="dateofbirth" id="dateofbirth">
                  <form action="/action_page.php">
                  <h5 class = "card-title mb-0"> 
                      To:  <input type="date" name="dateofbirth" id="dateofbirth">
                      <form action="/action_page.php">
                      </h5> </div>
            <div class="card-body-sales">

              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center pb-4"></div>
                <div id="bar-traffic-sales"></div>
              </div>

              <canvas id="barChartSales" ></canvas>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The above example doesn't have data related dates at all, then how can you filter it by Dates?

Comment: @Ravikumar I found an example online but since i know nothing about js i don't know when the chart is filtering the data, and i think i know where the online example is filtering the data but don't know where to place it in this function.I'm going to add it to the question.